# Core Data questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have this JSON

```
"extra_information"=>
   {"pickup"=>{"latitude"=>-5.77877092, "longitude"=>-35.20272732, "address"=>"Street foo bar, 20"},
    "location"=>{"latitude"=>-5.77877092, "longitude"=>-35.20272732, "address"=>"Street foo bar, 20"},
    "destination"=>{"latitude"=>-5.80037532, "longitude"=>-35.18345833, "address"=>"Street foo bar, 20"},
    "ride_detail"=>
     {"request_id"=>"be7646ca-73ae-4bb2-930b-280317380518",
      "duration"=>"00:11:32",
      "distance"=>"1.87",
      "map_url"=>"https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/map"},
    "product_detail"=>{"name"=>"xxxx", "time_cost"=>"0.17", "rate_base"=>"2.5", "distance_cost"=>"1.2"}
```

I tried to create an entity "extra_information" but I was not successful. I am in doubt about the relationships that need to be done. Do I need to create entities for the "Product Detail" and "Ride Detail" and make the relationship with "Extra Information" or add both to it? I am doing this because these data will be read in an HTTP request

Edit1 : Here's my coredata entity now

[Extra Information Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EdpR.png)

The entity is making a relationship with the Product Detail, Ride Detail and Location. Would that be correct?

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more detail.

Comment: @Abizern i add more information now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Entity of ProductDetail and add a relationship to multiple Entitys to it **if it is the same information** that should be used for multiple entitys.

However, If the information is **different** for each Entity relationship->detail, you need to create two entitys for RideDetail and ProductDetail with "extra_information".

I am not sure what your failure is but this is the guideline.